# How to conditionally enable/disable cell renderer in Ag-Grid?

Tags: ag-grid

I am using ag-grid cell renderer and I have created a separate component for it. Based on some condition, I want to conditionally make the cell renderer component enable or disable.

{
      headerName: 'Look up values', field: 'LOOKUP', editable: false, cellRenderer:'lookupRenderer'}

I want to enable/disable 'lookupRenderer' based on conditions.

Comment: By disable, you mean remove it entirely from the columnDefs? or just leave it empty ?

Comment: Actually lookupRenderer is a button and on it's click I am opening a popup. So want to enable/disable the button when some other value in grid changes. But look like cell renderer renderers cell data initially when grid loads and then when I change some value in other grid columns, that won't be reflected in renderer component.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inline `cellRenderer` should be used only for simple cases.
To achieve button-click handling inside own [`cellRenderer`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/) you need to create `component` for that.

Your component would be like that:

```js
    @Component({
        selector: 'custom-button-cell',
        template: `<button [disabled]="!params.node.data.enableButton" (click)="handleClick()">{{params.value}}</button>`,
        styles: [``]
    })

    export class ConditionalRenderer implements ICellRendererAngularComp {
        private params: any;

        agInit(params: any): void {
            this.params = params;
        }

        refresh(): boolean {
           return true;
        }

       handleClick() {
          alert(`Clicked: ${this.params.value}`);
       }
    }
```

Here is [worked plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/ucHKk5awHWHPeZxemtMU?p=preview)

Don't forget, that your `component` should be included to `frameworkComponents` inside `gridOptions` or as `[frameworkComponents]` html attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same requirement and I achieved this via inline cell renderer

**Code:**

```
{   
    headerName: 'lookup', 
    suppressMenu: true,
    width:130,
    suppressSorting: true, 
    cellRenderer: (params) => {
   
    const element = document.createElement('span');
    let buttonname;
    let template;
    if (params.data.USER_ROLE_END_DATE=='')
    {
      buttonname = 'Disable Role'
      template= `<button type="button" style="height: 25px;line-height: 0.5"data-action-type="Disablerole"  class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-xs btn-block" ;
      >
      ${buttonname} 
     </button>`
    }
    else
    {
      buttonname = 'Enable Role'
      template= `<button type="button" style="height: 25px;line-height: 0.5"data-action-type="Disablerole"  class="btn btn-outline-success btn-xs btn-block" ;
      >
      ${buttonname} 
     </button>`
    }

   element.innerHTML = template;
    return element;
   }
       
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kapil, this looks fine. But I need to call a function on click of the button. Do you have any idea where can I place it in the above code?

Comment: Use below event in the grid html                     (rowClicked)="onRowClicked($event)" also in the ts file use below code public onRowClicked(e) {
    if (e.event.target !== undefined) {
        let data = e.data;
        let datanode = e.node;
        let actionType = e.event.target.getAttribute("data-action-type");
        switch(actionType) {
            case "AddRole":
                return this.onActionAddroleClick(data);
            case "Disablerole":
                return this.onActionDisableroleClick(datanode);        }    }
    console.log(this.gridColumnApi)}

Comment: data-action-type="Disablerole"  will be used to identify the action at rowclick.

Answer (score 0):

Renderer Template -

```
<button type="button" (click)="placeOrder($event)" >Submit</button>
```

Renderer Component -

```
agInit(params: any) {
    this.params = params;
  }

placeOrder(event: Event): void {
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.params.onClick(..);
  }
```

Grid component which defines coldefs -

```
columnDefs = [
    { headerName: '', field: "Test", cellRenderer: 'rendererName', 
      cellRendererParams: {
      onClick: this.placeOrder.bind(this)
      }
    }
private placeOrder(obj: any): void {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is for Angular

I faced the same issue. My case was to prevent rendering a delete button on one cell. So, I created a cellRenderer Component as follow

// Angular

````
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { ICellRendererAngularComp } from 'ag-grid-angular';
   
@Component({
  selector: 'app-icon-button-renderer',
  templateUrl: './Icon-button-renderer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./Icon-button-renderer.component.css'],
})
export class IconButtonRendererComponent implements ICellRendererAngularComp {
    
  params: any;
  iconName: string = "";
  hidden: boolean = false;
  agInit(params: any): void {
    this.params = params;
    this.iconName = params.iconName;
    this.hidden = this.params.node.data.name === params.preventionName;
  }
    
  refresh(params?: any): boolean {
    return true;
  }
    
  onClick(event: any) {
    if (this.params.onClick instanceof Function) {
    
      this.params.onClick(this.params);
    }
  }
}
```
````

**The Angular Html template** for IconButtonComponent is

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="hidden===false" [ngIfElse]="Nobutton" #Withbutton>
  <button mat-icon-button color="warn" (click)="onClick($event)">
    <mat-icon class="mat-18">
      {{iconName}}
    </mat-icon>
  </button>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #Nobutton></ng-template>
```

First, I use `*ngIf="hidden"` and `[ngIf]="hidden"`on the `button` tag but it doesn't work, but it worked with `ng-template`