# Ag-grid disable a button from a specific row

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

In my work they have this ag-grid in angular, and with cell renderer, they create a button for each row, but after certain condition they want me to disable the button, but I have no idea on how to do that

grid.ts

```
this.frameworkComponents = {
  buttonRenderer: BtnRendererComponent,
  viewButtonRenderer: BtnViewRendererComponent
};
this.submissionCols = [
  {
    headerName: 'Process', field: 'id', filter: true, sortable: true, width: 100, cellClass: 'grid-cell-centered',
    cellRenderer: 'viewButtonRenderer', hide: !this.hide,

    onCellClicked: this.onBtnClick.bind(this),
  },
  {
    headerName: this.hide ? 'Request Status' : 'Review Status', width: 150,
    field: 'reviewStatus',
    filter: true,
    sortable: true
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Review Type',
    field: 'reviewType',
    filter: true,
    sortable: true
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Reviewer',
    field: 'reviewer',
    filter: true,
    sortable: true
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Request Type',
    field: 'reviewRequestItem',
    filter: true,
    sortable: true,
    hide: !this.hide
  },
  {
    headerName: 'In Reference To',
    field: 'reference',
    filter: true,
    sortable: true,
    hide: !this.hide
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Request Item',
    field: 'reviewRequestItem',
    filter: true,
    sortable: true,
    hide: this.hide
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Description',
    field: 'description',
    filter: true,
    sortable: true
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Responded',
    field: 'responded',
    filter: true,
    sortable: true,
    cellRenderer: (data) => {
      if (data.data.responded != null) {
        return moment(data.data.responded).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
      }
    }
  }

];
}
```

here is my class for viewButtonRenderer:

```
export class BtnViewRendererComponent implements ICellRendererAngularComp {
    params;
    label: string;
    colored: string;
    textColored: string;
    icon: string;

    agInit(params): void {
         this.params = params;
         this.label = this.params.data.id || null;
         this.colored = "red";

         if (params.column.colDef.headerName === "View") {
             this.icon = "details";
         } else {
             this.icon = "note";
         }
    }

    refresh(params?: any): boolean {
        return true;
    }

    onClick($event) {
        if (this.params.onClick instanceof Function) {
            // put anything into params u want pass into parents component
            const params = {
                event: $event,
                rowData: this.params.node.data
               // ...something
            };
            this.params.onClick(params);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm new with ag-grid and I could really use a hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear what you want to achieve. Do you want to disable a button in a CellRenderer, several buttons from different rows, or several rows, or a few cells in a given row...

In a scenario, when you want to disable a button in a particular row due to some global state of the grid or a state of component that hosts that grid, you should pass that condition into your renderer as a variable (as indicated by Sharanya) either as a cellRendererParams

```
gridOptions: GridOptions = {
    ...,
    columnDefs: [
        ...,
        {
            headerName: 'Responded',
            field: 'responded',
            filter: true,
            sortable: true,
            cellRenderer: (data) => myCustomRenderer(data),
            cellRendererParams: { condition: myCondition }
        }
    ]
}
```

or as a context containing the parent itself with access to the variable/condition and have a possibility to communicate directly to the parent

```
gridOptions: GridOptions = {
    ...,
    context: {
        parent: this
    }
}
```

This is well explained in the official [doc](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/). Then in your renderer component you check the condition for disabling the button taking into account you row. In my example, which you can find [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-custom-editor), I want to disable OK button until the validation is finished and passed for a form that consists of a row.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Have a variable in your renderer which will check if a certain value is passed from the parent and disable ur button with the [disabled] tag in the cell renderer's html.

Possible duplicate of this:

[how-to-conditionally-enable-disable-cell-renderer-in-ag-grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52510746/how-to-conditionally-enable-disable-cell-renderer-in-ag-grid)

Let me know if it works

Comment: but I don't want the whole grid to be disabled, just a few fields, if I have 5 fields of data, perhaps 2 should be disabled because of the condition

Comment: This is relevant to that particular cell only. You will be passing only the param.node or param.value in any case. You can create a fiddle or a plunkr to allow me to edit and show you in case you need it working.