# Using AG-Grid, disable/enable fields in the same row when a value is changed

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have an AG-Grid, containing several cells which need to be enabled/disabled & cleared based on the value selected in a particular column.

```
|  col_a   |  col_b   |  col_c   | ... | col_t  | ... |
|----------|----------|----------|-----|--------|-----|
| editable | editable | editable | ... | Type W | ... |
| editable | X        | X        | ... | Type X | ... |
| editable | X        | editable | ... | Type Y | ... |
| X        | X        | editable | ... | Type Z | ... |
```

If the user changes in `col_t` type from say `Type W` to `Type X`, then the values in `col_b` and `col_c` needs to be cleared (or set to "N/A" or something) and the cell disabled for editing. If they then change it from `Type X` to `Type Y`, then `col_c` needs to be re-enabled for editing (and the value left at "N/A").

I've looked at the suggestion for [creating a new cell-renderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52510746/how-to-conditionally-enable-disable-cell-renderer-in-ag-grid), but that only seems to handle the enabling/disabling, is on column not a row basis, and doesn't seem to address the value reset.

I have the "rules" squeezed into an keyed object array:

```js
{
  "Type W":["col_a","col_b","col_c",],
  "Type X":["col_a",],
  "Type Y":["col_a","col_c",],
  "Type Z":["col_c",],
}
```

... and I suspect that I can could change the values of the other cells in the row by setting an `onCellValueChanged` handler for `col_t` for like this:

```js
onCellValueChanged: (params) => {
  params.newValue
  const rules = {
    "Type W":["col_a","col_b","col_c",],
    "Type X":["col_a",],
    "Type Y":["col_a","col_c",],
    "Type Z":["col_c",],
  }
  if ( params.oldValue !== params.newValue) {
    theRule.forEach( (columnName) => {
    if( theRule.indexOf(columnName) === -1 ) {
        // reset value
        params.data[columnName] = 'n/a'

        // disable cell
        // ???
      } else {
        //enable row
        // ???

      }
    })
  }
}
```

However, from the comments you can see I'm not sure how to disable/enable cells in just the row I'm in. I'm guessing its via the api and `getRowNode(id)`, but I can't see it.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per docs -

> It is possible to have only a few cells in a column editable; to do
>   so, instead of colDef.editable=true, you can specify a callback that
>   will get called for each cell displayed for that column. If you return
>   true the cell will be editable.

Have you considered defining a callback for `editable` property for all columns. You can customize the callback as per the rules you have and add this to each of the colDef. This should handle the edit enable/disable part.

```
editable: this.customEditFn.bind(this)
...
customEditFn(params){
    //params.node - for row identity
    //params.column - for column identity

   // add your rules here
   // return boolean based  on rules
}
```

You should continue using `onCellValueChanged` callback for resetting values though.

More details [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editing/#enabling-editing-in-a-column)

Comment: I'm not sure how that triggers the change in the other cells in a row? The data is quite dynamic, and it seemed more sensible to attach some sort of trigger to the cell that changes, rather than have the whole sheet re-calculate whenever a cell changes?

Comment: This wont trigger changes in other cells, but this gives you finer control on handling editable logic. For changing values in other cells, you will have to use onCellValueChanged callback. SO the proposed solution is combination of editable + onCellValueChanged

Comment: I've given you the answer, but honestly, I've abandoned the AG Grid library - and gone with JExcel. Their approach is much closer to what you'd expect, and disabling a cell is pretty much just `table.records[y][x].element.classList.toggle('readonly')` where x and y are the coordinates of the cell in the grid. Very, very clean API.